# vs code c++ extension installation problem

Tags: visual-studio-code

from a youtube tutorial i have installed vscode and now i was trying to install c++ estensions for c++ but the downloading is liked frozen.
enter image description here
i have given the name of extension i am trying to install and the downloading status also.
the downloading status is not showing any progress in it despite having a good connectivity.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuOrg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voTrx.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just the vagaries of the internet, your (presumed) Windows system, or VS Code itself. Shutdown and restart everything and try it again. I've experienced this on occasion and just restarting VS Code fixed it.